# Alternative for deprecated GWT Textbox setKey(char) method

Tags: java, internet-explorer, gwt

The setKey(char) method is used in our application( used GWT 2.3.0) to change user input in a TextBox to Uppercase character-wise on key press. Since GWT 1.6 the setKey is deprecated as it worked only in IE. It is working fine in IE8 but doesn't work in IE11. I tried to find an alternative for this method but couldn't get any. How can i convert it to uppercase in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written the logic inside onKeyUp event method to get the value from textbox and convert it to uppercase and then set it to textbox again as given below.It is working fine.

```
  public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
        String input = textbox.getText();
        textbox.setText(input.toUpperCase());
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the CSS property `text-transform: uppercase;` to your textbox but keep in mind that `TextBox.getValue();` wont return an uppercase string since this css property is just "visual". 
probably you have to use `String.toUpperCase()` also...